# Javascript - Increase time dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have a dashboard page, where I have some time values that come back from the server. These times are in the format: HH:MM:SS (13:05:01, for example). But that value only refresh when then user reloads the page. I would like to do some javascript to keep that value going on... what's the easiest easy to do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What will happen if on page reload the time will not be equal to the calculated one?

Comment: @LelioFaieta guess that it's not desirable, but wouldn't be a big problem, and the server value is the trustable one. That javascript would be for improve the user xp a little bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would go about doing it with setInterval, just set it to run the function that updates your time, and set the interval, to 1000 (milliseconds) for it to change every second. You can look [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) for more info.

Comment: Polling is not a good idea in terms of performance and stability

Answer (score 1):

Can you give me a valid reason to spam the servers with requests for time over and over again when the user machine has high probability of having perfectly valid time -  is connected to internet and unless user has not messed with it it's correct.

(You might have to offset for zones, not 100% about that)

**Downsides of approach to ask server over and over for current time:**

- You will suffer from latency
- You will spam server without valid need
- Ability to scale is sinking very fast both by items and users

If you need to check user time matches yours, do a 1 request at the start and then compare times with a bit of offset allowed. If times don't match set the correct time on front from back and display user device time +- whatever the difference was. If they match close enough display user's device time.

Deletes all the negatives. Adds no new negatives.

EDIT upon comment:

Oh, that makes more sense. You can query server on reload but if you expect to reaload a lot (and you need a time to be static after once being set up) you can use localStorage to store it on new browsers or cookies (work for older browsers as well).

For something that is not likely to change I would not query the server again if I don't need to. In case you need / wanna query the server again specifficaly when page loads or reloads you can add this to element on that page `onload="myFunction()"`

In `myFunction` handle to call to the back and binding to text of element displaying it.

Comment: Guess you didn't got it. I won't be requesting the time for server all the time. That values come when the server render the pages (ex 14:05:02). I only want my javascript keep refreshing that time, cause that value will only be refreshed if the user reloads the page and the server renders the new value